# Как сравнить определенный элемент переменной `int` с каким либо числом `str` в операторе `if`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, int

К примеру так:

```
x = int(input("Введи чесло"))
if x[-1] == "1":
    print ("Число заканчивается на 1")
```

Выдает ошибку: `'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Так надо x = input("Введи число: ")

Comment: Либо `int` уберите, либо вместо `x[-1] == "1"` Укажите `x%10 == 1`.

Comment: @Виктор, я попробовал:
`l = False
while l == False:
    x = input("Введи число")
    if x[-1] == 1:
        print ("Число заканчивается на 1")
    try:
        x = int(x)
        l = True
    except ValueError:
        print("введите целое число")`
Добавил функцию, чтобы человек вводил именно число, и внутри нее изменил тип переменной на `int`

Comment: @ЕгорКольцов if x[-1] == "1"

Comment: @ЕгорКольцов сделайте отдельно попытку приведения к int, чтобы проверить что введено именно число, но последнюю цифру берите из введенной строки. Или проверяйте последнюю цифру через остаток деления на 10.